# cakephp dropdown from another table

Tags: cakephp-2.1

i have two tables

**voices**:

- id
- Lecturer_id
- ...

**Lecturers**:

- id
- Lecturer
- code

add.ctp is for voices but there is a drop-down which list lecturers. then the id of Lecturer should be saved in Lecturer_id of voices table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i solved the issue and wanted to share it with u:

in Voice module:

```
public $belongsTo = 'Lecturer';
```

and i added some code to Add action in Voicescontroller:

```
    $this->set('lecturers', $this->Voice->Lecturer->find(
            'list',
            array(
                'fields' => array('Lecturer.Lecturer'),
                'order' => array('Lecturer.Lecturer')
            )));
```

and in add.ctp for my dropdown:

```
        echo $this->Form->input('lecturer_id',  array(
            'options' => array($lecturers),
            'empty' => '(choose one)'
             ));
```